# Unable to access configure managed account in SP 2013

Tags: central-administration

I have a test lab and on the host machine I installed AD, SQL and Sharepoint 2013. Everything went fine until I wanted to configure managed accounts through Security Tab. I got this error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please I really need help on this to proceed as this has taken me two days without resolution.

Comment: Have you tried PowerShell? Like Get-SPMangedAccount Set-SPManagedAccount and [New-SPManagedAccount](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607831.aspx)?

Comment: is it brand new installation? do you have the any account exist in the managed account?

Comment: Is a brand new installation. Have used Get-SPMangedAccount but I get the error: the term Get-SPMangedAccount is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: first you have to run the powershell commans in sharepoint powershell console. start > all program > sharepoint > right click and run as admin....are you getting any correlation id?

Comment: It was run as admin. FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException

Comment: can you share the screen, for me looks like your sharepoint installation is not stable.

Comment: i would like to attach the screen shot but there is no option to do that

Comment: Hello Waqas, after running Sharepoint snapin I can now run powershell cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that one of the registered SharePoint "managed accounts" didn't exist in active directory. I was able to see this by executing `get-spmanagedaccount`. This returned a list of account names, one of which didn't exist. I then executed `remove-spmanagedaccount "domain\nonexistentaccount"`. As soon as this was done I was once again able to access the Configure Managed Accounts screen.